# Need help in turn off docker in 'Autogen AutoBuilder"

Tags: python, autogen

I am new and struggling to turn off Docker. I like to either set 'use_docker': false or set up environment variable. Either option will work. Thanks for your help. The screenshot has been enclosed.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Docker in AutoGen version 0.2.8 and later, set code_execution_config to false in your configuration, as Docker is now enabled by default.

For a detailed guide on how to make this change, you can watch this tutorial: https://youtu.be/aWml0ncqPnU?t=195